# Profiling Execution Time of ResNet

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, profiling, conv-neural-network, resnet

I used CIFAR-10 dataset to train and evaluate ResNet on Intel i7 CPU. 
(ResNet model is in Tensorflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet)

Now, I am interested in profiling the app i.e. determining the execution time of the top functions. Analysis with the functions sort_stats() gives information about the top function only. Moreover, using profiling tool cProfile throws the following error --

python3 -m profile cifar10_main.py

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
TypeError: main() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

It would be great if someone can help me out with collecting (nearly accurate, and with function level, or line-level) profiling information for ResNets. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [tf.profiler](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md). Unless you're executing eagerly, the interesting performance issues (once the graph is built) will be in TensorFlow C++ code rather than Python.